# Android Kotlin creating SpannableString from another SpannableString loses spans

Tags: android, kotlin, spannablestring

I'm working on creating my own MarkdownTextView.

In this particular instance, I'm sifting through a body of text parsing out italic tags example:

```
Here is text, and *here is italic text*, and maybe *more* italic text
```

I have a **regex function** that does the sifting for me:

```
(\*[^*])(.*?)([^*]\*)
```

**Below is the code** that I am using **to replace all of the italic snippets**:

```
val commentBody = "Here is text, and *here is italic text*, and maybe *more* italic text"
val check = "(\*[^*])(.*?)([^*]\*)".toRegex()
val newSpan = SpannableString(commentBody.replace(check, { result ->
    val innerSpan = SpannableString(result.value.substring(1, result.value.length - 1))
    innerSpan.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, innerSpan.length, spanFlag)
    return@replace innerSpan
}))
```

My regex is working properly, and

```
Here is text, and *here is italic text*, and maybe *more* italic text
```

is correctly converted to show

```
Here is text, and here is italic text, and maybe more italic text
```

But nothing is italicized. I debugged this, and it confirms my fear that when setting the italics span inside of that transform, and using that to setup my new spannable string, that I'm losing all of those spans.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested this is my answer:

```
val commentBody = "Here is text, and *here is italic text*, and maybe *more* italic text"
val check = "(\\*[^*])(.*?)([^*]\\*)".toRegex()
val spannableStringBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder(commentBody.replace("*", ""))
check.findAll(commentBody).map { it.value.substring(1, it.value.length - 1) }.forEach { 
    val start = spannableStringBuilder.indexOf(it)
    val end = start + it.length
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, innerSpan.length, spanFlag)
}
return spannableStringBuilder
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at [`String.replace`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html), you'll find, that the `SpannableString` you return is actually used as a `CharSequence` for `transform: (MatchResult) -> CharSequence`.

Also you're creating the outer `SpannableString` from a pure `String` only.

Thus you never had the information available. You could have a look into `SpannableStringBuilder` and use it with a different approach like using a tokenizer or a custom Markdown span which removes the markup syntax on the fly.